# Adding lists names as plot titles in lapply call in R

Tags: r, plot

```
sample <- 
structure(list(GB05 = structure(c(22L, 34L, 26L, 2L), .Dim = 4L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("98", "100", "102", "106")), .Names = ""), class = "table"), 
    GB18 = structure(c(8L, 14L, 70L), .Dim = 3L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
        c("173", "175", "177")), .Names = ""), class = "table"), 
    GB06 = structure(c(2L, 16L, 48L, 10L, 10L, 6L), .Dim = 6L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
        c("234", "238", "240", "242", "244", "246")), .Names = ""), class = "table"), 
    GB27 = structure(c(2L, 28L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 15L, 
    17L, 4L, 5L), .Dim = 12L, .Dimnames = structure(list(c("145", 
    "147", "149", "151", "156", "159", "165", "167", "169", "171", 
    "173", "175")), .Names = ""), class = "table"), GB24 = structure(c(2L, 
    4L, 41L, 10L, 6L, 2L, 14L, 2L, 3L), .Dim = 9L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
        c("240", "241", "242", "243", "244", "247", "249", "251", 
        "253")), .Names = ""), class = "table"), GB28 = structure(c(30L, 
    22L, 2L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Dim = 9L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
        c("363", "364", "365", "367", "371", "377", "380", "384", 
        "390")), .Names = ""), class = "table"), GB15 = structure(c(12L, 
    16L, 43L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Dim = 6L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
        c("142", "144", "146", "147", "148", "152")), .Names = ""), class = "table"), 
    GB02 = structure(c(6L, 78L, 4L), .Dim = 3L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
        c("194", "197", "200")), .Names = ""), class = "table"), 
    GB10 = structure(c(2L, 36L, 7L, 1L, 16L, 20L), .Dim = 6L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
        c("124", "126", "128", "130", "132", "134")), .Names = ""), class = "table"), 
    GB14 = structure(c(3L, 6L, 7L, 37L, 7L), .Dim = 5L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
        c("181", "184", "187", "193", "196")), .Names = ""), class = "table")), .Names = c("GB05", 
"GB18", "GB06", "GB27", "GB24", "GB28", "GB15", "GB02", "GB10", 
"GB14"))
```

How to get the names in this list to appear as plot titles in this lapply call (one title for each plot) ?

```
dev.new()
par(mfrow=c(2,5))
lapply(sample,function(x) plot(x,main=names[x]))
```

I don't understand why main=names[x] won't work.

Comment: Your `dput` output is not correctly copy/pasted. It gives error when trying to copy.

Comment: @Arun Corrected, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Chargaff, nope. *Now* it's fixed. Your first line read `sample <- dput(afn)`. You don't need to include that `dput(afn)` part.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 could you please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59344173/in-r-how-to-automatically-plots-based-on-lists

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `lapply` on the names of the list items instead:

```
lapply(names(afn), function(x) plot(afn[[x]], main=x))
```

[image]

To see *why* you aren't getting your names, run `lapply(afn, function(x) names(x))` gives you the *names* of each list item or something else. Try the same with `lapply(names(afn), function(x) x)` and compare the difference. Then, remember that we can extract a single list item by name by using `[[`.