# Move title of plots in a list of plots in R

Tags: r, plot, lapply

I have a list of plots that I have assigned names to, and then converted to plot titles as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/14790376/9335733. The titles happen to appear over the top x-axis title and so I attempt to move them as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44618277/9335733. The overall code looks as follows:

```
lapply(names(Cast.files), function (x) plot(Cast.files[[x]],
                                        main = x,
                                        adj = 0, #adjust title to the farthest left
                                        line =2.5 #adjust title up 2.5
                                        )
   )
```

It should be noted that `plot` is now converted from base R to the `oce` package for analyzing oceanographic data, but calls the same arguments from base R `plot`.

The problem becomes that in trying to move the title, the axis labels move as well and overlap. Any suggestions?

Edit: Here is what the image looks like before:
    [image]

And after:
    [image]

Comment: would you mind show the plot image?

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look into the `oma=` argument in `par()`, which provides an "outer" margin which can be used to put a nice title. Something like:

```
library(oce)
data(ctd)
par(oma=c(0, 0, 1, 0))
plot(ctd)
title('Title', outer=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by adding a `title` argument outside of the `plot` function as follows:

```
lapply(names(Cast.files), function (x) plot(Cast.files[[x]], 
                                        which = c("temperature", "salinity", "sigmaT","conductivity"),
                                        Tlim = c(11,12), 
                                        Slim = c(29,32),
                                        col = "red") 
+ title(main = x, adj = 0.48, line = 3.5)#adding the titles at a specific location
   )
```

This allowed for plots that looked like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use the title function, rather than setting main within plot, it would allow you to change the line without affecting anything else in the plot.