# in R, how to automatically plots based on lists?

Tags: r, r-plotly

I've got a survey results for two products categories, here is the data

```
surveyresults<-data.frame("Name"=c("Adam","John"),
"Gender"=c("m","m"),
"City"=c("Sydney","Melbourne"),
"Product"=c("Fashion","Electronics"),
"fash_pay_cash"=c(5,"NA"),
"fash_pay_card"=c(5,"NA"),
"elc_pay_cash"=c("NA",5),
"elc_pay_card"=c("NA",6),
"fash_DlvTime_morning"=c(5,"NA"),
"fash_DlvTime_afternoon"=c(7,"NA"),
"elc_DlvTime_morning"=c("NA",5),
"elc_DlvTime_afternoon"=c("NA",8))
surveyresults
```

and i need to plot each element in this list

```
fshnprxlist<-list("fash_pay","fash_DlvTime")
```

which represents the prefix of each column needed to be ploted and should be the plot title name
[image: like this]

since I'm the survey creator, so i built it based on this lists

```
list1<-list("fashion","electronics")
listPM<-list("cash","card")
listDT<-list("morning","afternoon")
fshlistPM<-paste("fash_pay",listPM,sep="_")
fshlistDT<-paste("fash_DlvTime",listDT,sep="_")
elcprxlist<-list("elc_pay","elc_DlvTime")
elclistPM<-paste("elc_pay",listPM,sep="_")
elclistDT<-paste("elc_DlvTime",listDT,sep="_")
```

my request is simply, dynamically create plot for each element of the 1st list using the column that starts with the "text of each element in the first elements

Comment: from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24806/dropping-unused-levels-in-facets-with-ggplot2, we can do `facet_wrap(vars(group), scales = "free_x")`

Comment: @A.Suliman Thank you for this simple, yet highly effective tip :)

Comment: Dear @A. Suliman, if I have a reactive dataframe  `df()` and I need to remove a prefix  `input$selectId` from each row in  `Col1`, I tried this  `df()$Col1<-sub(input$selectId,"", df()$Col1)`  but it doesn't work

Comment: You can not assign a value to a reactive expression i.e. using `<-` with `df()`. so you need to do this inside the reactive or when you want to use `df()` by `df1 <- df();df1$Col1<-sub(input$selectId,"", df1$Col1)` then use `df1`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it with my data

Comment: @A.Suliman if you have time, could you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431981/how-to-create-two-independent-drill-down-plot-using-highcharter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we could reshape into 'long' format and then use `ggplot` to plot

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
p1 <- surveyresults %>%
      type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = fash_pay_cash:elc_DlvTime_afternoon, 
        names_to = c("group", ".value"), names_pattern = "^(\\w+_\\w+)_(\\w+)$") %>% 
      pivot_longer(cols = cash:afternoon, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
      group_by(group, name) %>%
      summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = group)) + 
        geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
        facet_wrap(vars(group))

ggplotly(p1)
```

-output

[image]

---

Or we can use `facet_wrap_paginate` from `ggforce`

```
library(ggforce)
p1 <- surveyresults %>%
       type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
       pivot_longer(cols = fash_pay_cash:elc_DlvTime_afternoon, 
         names_to = c("group", ".value"),
               names_pattern = "^(\\w+_\\w+)_(\\w+)$") %>% 
       pivot_longer(cols = cash:afternoon, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
       group_by(group, name) %>%
       summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
       ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = group)) + 
         geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
         facet_wrap_paginate(~ group, ncol = 1, nrow = 2, page = 2)

n <- n_pages(p1)
pdf('surveyout.pdf')
for(i in seq_len(n)) print(p1 + 
           facet_wrap_paginate(~ group, ncol = 1, nrow = 2, page = i))
dev.off()
```

---

Or it can be split into smaller subsets, create ggplot in each and then apply the plotly on it separately

```
library(purrr)
lstOut <- surveyresults %>%
           type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
           pivot_longer(cols = fash_pay_cash:elc_DlvTime_afternoon, 
              names_to = c("group", ".value"),
                names_pattern = "^(\\w+_\\w+)_(\\w+)$") %>% 
           pivot_longer(cols = cash:afternoon, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
           group_by(group, name) %>%
           summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
           ungroup %>%
           group_split(grp =(as.integer(factor(group, 
               levels = unique(group)))%/% 3) + 1) %>%
           map(~ 
             ggplot(.x, aes(x = name, y = value, fill = group)) + 
             geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
             facet_wrap(vars(group)) -> p)

ggplotly(lstOut[[1]])
ggplotly(lstOut[[2]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Actually my real data include more than 87 variables, which means that the plot x axis will show 83 variable beside morning, afternoon, card, cash..., each plot will not exceed 7 variables with values. additionally i will post 1 product category each page "fashion" for example, exactly as attached in the image above

Comment: @JohnSmith  You can split it to different pages with [facet_wrap_paginate](https://rdrr.io/cran/ggforce/man/facet_wrap_paginate.html)

Comment: @JohnSmith  You can also split into list and use that to create ggplot in each and save it i.e. after `summarise` step  `lstout <- ... summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%  ungroup %>% group_split(grp =(as.integer(factor(group, levels = unique(group)))%/% 3) + 1)`

Comment: @JohnSmith  I updated with splitting into different groups and plotting separately

Comment: @JohnSmith  If I find a way, will provide solution

Comment: @JohnSmith  Sure, i did check yesterday, but couldn't come up with a solution